# iOS app with watchkit targets: `The executable was signed with invalid entitlements` error for distribution profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

There are many SO posts regarding the error message `The executable was signed with invalid entitlements` when installing and running a distribution build in preparation for the appstore release. I have tried many answers without success, and I believe my situation regarding the watch targets is somewhat different, thus might need additional insights.

[image]

My app has three targets: MyApp, MyApp WatchKit Extension, MyApp WatchKit App. They each have App IDs created according to the naming requirements: `com.Company.MyApp`, `com.Company.MyApp.watchkitapp.watchkitextension`, `com.Company.MyApp.watchkitapp`.

We know that for the entitlements to work, the services enabled in Apple Developer Member Center corresponding to an App ID need to be exactly the same as the services in Capabilities for the respective app target in Xcode.

The issue is that Capabilities tab for the watchkit app targets doesn't contain all the services listed in the Member Center. For instance, here is the setup for MyApp Watchkit App in member center:
[image]

Note that `Game Center` and `In-App Purchase` are enabled by default, and can't be disabled. (If you click the Edit button you'll notice that the disable option is greyed out).

But here's the `Capabilities` tab for MyApp Watchkit App target:
[image]

Unlike the main target, for the watch target only `App Groups` capability is available. As a result, there's no way for me to turn on `Game Center` and `In-App Purchase` in Xcode. The WatchKit Extension target has more capabilities, but still is missing `Game Center` and `In-App Purchase`.

In the past, before I added the watch targets, making sure the capabilities match those in Member Center always fixes this issue for me. I believe this might be the same reason I am having the entitlement error (just a guess, might not even be the issue). However this time I can't seem to find a way to solve it, as I can't disable `Game Center` in Member Center, and I can't enable them for the watch targets in Xcode.

Things I've already tried from other answers but didn't work:

1. Starting from scratch, creating brand new app ids and provisioning profiles, turning off all capabilities both in the Capability tab in Xcode and in Member Center App ID settings, just to make sure they match; Deleting all old provisioning profiles from local, re-downloading, then setting the correct code signing and provisioning profiles in target Build Settings in Xcode.
2. Changing the name of the App ID to match the format of "XC com company myapp", in Member Center.
3. Quit & restart & clean & rebuild.
4. Deleted Code Signing Entitlements file in Building Settings -> Code Signing as many posts suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn on App Groups toggle switch.
All your 3 targets must have the same App Group ID - so also check it on Apple Developer portal under your credentials.

Comment: Hi, as shown in the screenshots, all app groups are turned off; I'm not using any app groups.

Answer (score -2):

Well I haven't really builded apps for Watch before. But as far as I know there's no need to make separate applications in the Developer Center for Watch applications. You can just create your main one only and that'll be enough...